# How to deal with pop up window?

Tags: robotframework

The process I want to automate is -

When a button (Sign in on https://www.happyeasygo.com/) is clicked
pop up window appears to login.
Then I have to enter my username:

Script

*** Settings** 
Library    SeleniumLibrary
 **Test Cases ***

Login test for happyeasygo

```
Open Browser      https://www.happyeasygo.com/         gc
Click Element    xpath://body[@class='modal-open']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]    
Maximize Browser Window
sleep  5
Click Element    xpath://a[contains(text(),'Sign in')]
Input Text       xpath://input[@id='user_phone']      959****701
```

And I am getting error for all below Elemet with locator not found:

```
Elemnt used :
//input[@id='user_phone']
/html[1]/body[1]/div[13]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/dl[1]/dd[1]/div[2]/input[1]
#user_phone
```

Please help?

Comment: Is the first modal closing and the sign in form opening normally before the error happens?

Answer (score 1):

Some more information would be useful (such as the actual error you are getting and the actual code being used.

However from what you've put I'd wager it's an issue with a timeout between clicking the Sign In screen and it trying to enter text in a box that hasn't rendered yet.

So you could add a wait clause until it appears

e.g.

```java
Click Element    xpath://a[contains(text(),'Sign in')]

// Wait for the element to appear on the page
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='user_phone']")));

Input Text  959****701
```

You could also use a wait instead of the "sleep  5", waiting instead for the Login option to appear. This prevents your test having artificial pauses that may not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be the case that the pop up `fisplayed` may not `br` web element. Mostly the pop up from chrome is identified as window pop up. Use [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) to handle this popup.